# div closing syntax in ie8

Tags: html, w3c

I've just discovered that using `<div />` instead of `<div></div>` completely destroys my page in IE8. Even though I only had the empty tag syntax in one single place, half the page didn't even render.

Is this a bug in IE8 or is this correct standards implementation? I'm astounded if this is correct behaviour and Microsoft have deliberately been this strict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML 4 the Div tags closing tag is required.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4

Check your standards :)